# Android App Layout is not correct in tab - Fine in mobile. How to fix?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-tabs

I created an app in android. App layout is working fine as I made in mobile, but ImageButtons in layout is distorted in tab which having big screen size than mobile?
I don't want to create different layout for each screen size.
Is there any other solution for this? Please help
Sample code appreciated

Comment: Why don't you want create different layout for each screen size?

Comment: Show us screen shots, please, so we can see what type of distortion you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

please mention the XML code.  if you are using pixel (PX) or wrap_content than use density Independence pixel (DIP) rather than that

Comment: I am using density Independence pixel (DIP)